# Cannot Add a Migration using EF Core 6

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-6.0

I have installed Visual Code 2022 preview (17.1). I have created a simple console app following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli

When I try to add a migration I get the following error

```
> dotnet ef migrations add One
Build started...
Build succeeded.
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' (x64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      6.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

Why would it want dot net 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Add the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design to your main project. if that doesn't work, add to your Data Access layer (project).